# Best way to use bookmarks or navigate in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, statet

I am using Eclipse (for writing Sweave files in R using StatEt, but I don't think that matters).  I want to find a way to navigate my large script file quickly in some automatic way.

Something like having eclipse add bookmarks automatically to places where it finds one of a set of strings, like

```
\begin{document}
\begin{column}
<<
\end{document}
```

I can't find anything suitably automatic, and the TexClipse plugin that is used with StaEt and comes with an outline view, doesn't work with sweave rnw files

Any ideas ?

Comment: What about right-clicking the row number and click "Add bookmark"? You can add view Bookmarks (Window > Show View > Bookmarks (you may have to click Other to find it) and have an outline of bookmarks right there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, whether you really meant that:

1. click in a line
2. rightclick in the grey area left to the line numbers
3. click "Add Bookmark..."
4. (re)name the bookmark

best,
te

Answer (score 0):

The latest testing version of StatET (3.0.0) comes with an Outline View to navigate Sweave documents (and ports all of the editing comfort of the R-script editor to the Sweave editor!)

You can find the archived update site for this testing version in the Downloads section of the StatET home page

http://www.walware.de/goto/statet